# Where is the body terminal of a FinFET connected usually in digital circuits and in analog circuits?

Tags: fet, finfet

What is the usual practice in industry regarding the body terminal of a FinFET?
Is it connected to the source to eliminate body effect?
Or is it connected either to the ground(nfet) or the supply(pfet)?
Is this matter handled differently in digital circuits and analog circuits?

Comment: I'd be surprised if it's different from any other MOSFET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FinFET is just a specific structure of a mosfet. It's connected the same way as a normal planar mosfet. The only difference is that the channel is surrounded by the gate on 3 sides (not just one side as a planar fet), hence it can be smaller (this "multi-gate" layout mitigates short channel effects).

You'd usually connect the body to the most negative or positive volage in the circuit (depends if it's an N channel or P channel), but this is not neccesrrily always the case (there are some very specific cases when you'd want to do otherwise).

EDIT: in standard processes (unless you use a special isolated gate NMOS), for N channel, you have no choice but to connect it to ground (Vss) because in an IC, all N channel mosfets share the common P-doped substrate, meaning they are (nearly) shorted together.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to add that the body effect is much less prominent in FinFETs than in planar FETs. The entire fin is depleted, so a FinFET has significantly less depletion charge than a planar FET with the same effective gate area. The little additional depletion charge under the fin that can result from \$V_B < V_S\$ doesn't affect the threshold voltage much.

For some data on the threshold voltage variation of a FinFET and a planar FET with body voltage, see Fig. 10 of C. H. Lee *et al.*, *Symp. VLSI. Technol.*, 2004, pp. 130-131, doi: [10.1109/VLSIT.2004.1345434](https://www.doi.org/10.1109/VLSIT.2004.1345434).